# PayPal Description Javascript

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am currently creating an app in appery.io and I have implemented the PayPal RESTApi into. Everything is correctly running but I can not get my description/order summary to look correct.... Currently I have this

```
var sReturn ='';
sReturn +="Recipient: "+ localStorage.getItem('giftcard_recipient');
sReturn +="Recipient Email: "+ localStorage.getItem('giftcard_email');
sReturn +="Card Type: "+ localStorage.getItem('giftcard_type');
sReturn +="Card Amount: "+ localStorage.getItem('nPrice');
sReturn +="Note: "+ localStorage.getItem('giftcard_note');
return sReturn;
```

which in turn results in this....[image: current summary]

I dont know how to get the paypal order summary to look like the many I see, such as...[image: paypal]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how that works with apps, but on normal websites with shopping carts you need to send a couple of hidden fields to paypal to get the result you want. Some of them are required, some optional. Most important for you is probably:

`<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />`

Check out this site for more options:
[Paypal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

There is a good tutorial on how to build a shopping cart and send it via jQuery to Paypal:
[Creating a client-side shopping cart](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/13/create-client-side-shopping-cart/)